# rails asset pipeline repeating css link tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

My application.css file looks like this:

```
*= require_tree ./external
*= require_tree ./production
*= require_self
*= require custom
```

I have several questions:

1. Why do I need require_self?  Won't application.css automatically generate a css file that includes everything inside of it, so why do I need to say to include itself?
2. The file generates css link tags for every file it calls, and then repeats each file in the application.css file:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/external/font-awesome-2137eff45e0b64a17b4133bd2ddbdd78.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/external/font-classic1-75487e58c5e0c1ab46da239ad0414945.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/external/font-classic2-9acd884646fab77078ff59ccede6af64.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/external/font-classic3-640d45ed2364d0dff5a81ef9ce2c22fa.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/production/animate-5a353aa5390410216c837f4dbdf1e161.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/production/bootstrap-d2f563dbd757e49a399f0a7ed5febeae.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/production/contacters-64e62ddc273c2f5847f30d698ca14b67.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/production/jcagency-25ee42f4b0d3c4fe0df1eceb8f9fb6f8.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/production/owl.carousel-a12c5f6eb71a13cfc44317722283736c.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/production/owl.theme-691a2eb3c8d303b6416d9876419fec29.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/production/owl.transitions-1b9d47a45c85e9fa3f2f990b6d59519a.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/production/quotes-64e62ddc273c2f5847f30d698ca14b67.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/production/static_pages-64e62ddc273c2f5847f30d698ca14b67.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/production/style-3fe936e1b22ddf4d10e11085bac9a58c.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/production/styles-switcher-c79d19bcbdf90ee639dcfb1363d8f64c.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-951210d1179df1d65814be3ec67080c4.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/custom-235702796c9fbc52681919853d66009b.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
   ```

   Isn't this bad?  How do I get it to not repeat?

Answer (score 4):

1. You don't have to use `*= require_self`. What it does is it places all the css in **application.css** in position determined by order of those `require`s.
   In fact, it can be good to get rid of it, since you are supposed to avoid putting your css in **application.css** anyway.
   If you don't put `*= require_self` anywhere, css from self will still get loaded, but then it will be the last stylesheet included invariably.
2. In development mode **application.css** isn't compiled to one large file (In development mode, assets are served as separate files in the order they are specified in the manifest file: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-development). So it's normal that you have multiple files. It's likely that you don't have each file repeated in your **application.css**, do you?

Comment: I'm still not sure i understand what require_self does.  An application.css file with all of the files is still created at precompile even if I don't include a require_self...

Comment: This answer is technically correct but a bit confusing. `require_self` specifies *what order* the CSS contents of application.css are <link>'ed (in development) or concatenated (in production). In your example, application.css appears after style_switcher.css but before custom.css. If you removed `require_self`, application.css would appear at the end by default - IE after custom.css.

Comment: updated my answer a little so it's more clear. yes, it will still be created. but then (if you have default `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>` line in your `application.html.erb` and didn't change any default precompilation settings) you will have multiple stylesheet files at the dev env with nothing in `application.css` and all stylesheets compiled to `application.css` in the production env.